# Creating a button with discounts for additional items

Tags: paypal

Im looking to create a add to cart button that allows for discounts when adding items

1 for 10   2 for 19   3 for 28   etc.

I also want to be able to have the SHIPPING section of paypal know that 3 for 28 is actually 3 items

I currently am using a dropdown to discount but buyers that order 50 are being charged for 1 unit shipping

Answer (score 0):

You can insert variable 'discount_amount' and 'discount_amount2' to edit discount in Add to Cart button. Link below for your reference and you can search the key word 'discount_amount' and 'discount_amount2' for the details.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

For the Shipping section, it is relevant to the variable 'shipping' and 'shipping2'. You can also check them in the link above for the details.